# How to Retrieve Custom Data from Firebase In-App Messaging in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm currently working on integrating Firebase In-App Messaging into my Flutter application. While I've managed to display basic messages, I'm struggling to retrieve custom data associated with these messages. Specifically, I need to access additional information sent along with the message, such as user-specific details or custom event triggers. Can someone provide guidance or a code example on how to extract and utilize custom data from Firebase In-App Messaging within a Flutter app? Any insights or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

There is on message listen on fcm and i can retrieve data from it using

```dart
messageService.onMessageListen((message) {
      if (message.data != null && message.data!.isNotEmpty) {
```

like this and i want to know how to get custom data from in-app messaging

Comment: ` if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }`

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#foreground-messages